# DWM Gaps not aligned

Tags: window-manager, patch, dwm, tiling-wm

is there a way I can fix this?

[image]

If you check it a little closely, you can see that firefox actually goes a little bit under the terminal and I really don't like it.

I am using DWM with vanity-gaps.

Previously I was on i3wm, which had no problem like this with gaps.

I am attaching the config.h file of my DWM: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DD8qhpsDk1wZt0IsB8l-He4wrEd41pww/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly because of adhering to resize hints -- your terminal probably sets its height and width at the granularity of a monospace row or column, whereas your browser doesn't set any. You can permit dwm to ignore resize hints by setting `resizehints` to 0 in config.h.

Answer (score -2):

If you are on arch try:
curl -LO larbs.xyz/larbs.sh
su
sh larbs.sh

and follow the instructions then restart your computer.
Luke Smith it the man who wrote it check you his youtube channel.

Comment: Please don't encourage people to just randomly run scripts off of the internet, with no indication of what they do, how they should help those in the position of the questioner, or their efficacy or relevancy.